# removing all decimals in C

Tags: c, math, decimal

I need to do some math. Basically taking a user entered number dividing it by 64, then multiplying by 64, but for it to work properly, need to get rid of the decimals completely before multiplying.

Example:

```
150 is entered
150/64 = 2.34375 (need it to just be 2)
2 * 64 = 128
output = 128
```

Comment: Do an integer division. `150 / 64 = 2` and then `2 * 64 = 128`.

Comment: Post your code so we can see variable declarations.

Comment: Do you want to *round* the value, or *truncate* it? And do you want it only for output, or for internal calculations?

Comment: You are not clear. Adding "basically" does not magically make what you wrote say what you wish it said but doesn't say. Although it shows that you *know* that what you wrote doesn't say what you wish it said but doesn't say. Please clearly say what you want.

Comment: You don't have decimals anyway. A **binary** digital computer uses a binary representation, not a decimal for the standard types. Show a [mcve].

Comment: What are you doing? Are the numbers integers? If so, what do they count. Why do you need to round to the lowest (nearest?)  64. You might need either real or integer arithmetic, floor(), ceil() or  a rounding function.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this.

`floor(z/64)*64` [ works perfectly for positive `z` w.r.t op's requirement]

As Meik Vtune mentioned I should obviously add this that the same thing can be observed using simply `int` casting.(only when the value is in range of int) This is preferrable when negative number is used.

In case the number is too big that divided result may not be stored in an `int` then use floor.

In case of negative numbers like `-5.6` you want `-5`.

So for variable z which is double and the result won't fit in an int..

```
if(z<0)  z=-(floor(-z));
```

Comment: because using an `int` does the same without using any functions.

Comment: @MeikVtune.: Check the naswer it's much more clear. Thanks.

Comment: cast to `int` don't really work. Because a floating number can be very big. Cast to `int` only work with the range of a `int`. You should not say that cast to int is the "same" thing for positive value. The only safe way is to use `floor()` or verify that the value fit in an `int`

Comment: `floor` does not the same as integer division for negative numbers. Similar for a cast.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're dealing with `float`, you can use `lrintf()` function which receives a `float` as a parameter and returns a `long int`:

```
float pi = 3.1415;
printf("%li", lrintf(pi));
```

In case you're dealing with `double`, you can use `lrint()` function which receives a `double` as a parameter and returns a `long int`:

```
double pi = 3.1415;
printf("%li", lrint(pi));
```

OBS: **These functions are all declared in `math.h`.**

More about rounding and truncating functions:
https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Rounding-Functions.html

Answer (score -2):

If you define your input variable as short, int or long you will get only integer number part for free.

```
int input = 150;
int output = (input / 64) * 64; 
// Now output = 128.
```

Comment: `char` might not be able to hold `150`. Also the operation is not done on `char` or `short`.

Comment: @CodingLambdas char is depend on compiler preferences, in clang or gcc you can make it signed or unsigned. I ask again what is  the problem on short? Only one I can see is that it is small to hold big numbers.

Comment: Sorry, I just read Olaf's comment and immediately thought about signed / unsigned. You did nothing wrong.

Comment: @Ariel: I did not say there4 is a problem with`short`, just that the operaetion is never done in `short` nor `char`. And wheter `char` is signed or unsigned is not only a compiler preference, but also depends on the ABI. Specifically: it is implementation defined. It also is a matter of the guaranteed range of values a type can hold. On an target with 9 bit/byte, `signed char` can very well represent `150`.

Comment: @Olaf, yeah, we can speak a lot on various machine representations or exotic platforms, signed or unsigned, but it is not related to the idea: use of integer division.

Comment: Some of these "exotic" platforms have more devices in the wild than x86 ... And being precise is never wrong in answers read by beginners who take such answers literally.